# Extract an undetermined number of integers from a string

Tags: c, string, substring, scanf

I was wondering whether there's a better way of doing this; say we read stdin to a string using `fgets()` where the string includes a total of `n` integers (e.g. `5 16 2 34` for `n = 4`), what would be the best way of extracting them? There has got to be a better way than this hack:

```
for (i=0, j=0; i<n; ++i, j+=pos)
     sscanf(string+j, "%d%n", &array[i], &pos); // Using %n makes me feel dirty
```

I know it's possible (and *seemingly* easier) to simply use something like `for (i=0;i<n;++i) scanf("%d", array+i);` but I'd rather avoid using `scanf()` for obvious reasons.[¹](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Comment: Your solution might not be the prettiest thing on earth, but hey, it works. Just comment it properly and get on to other things.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strtol`. The following code reads exactly `n` integers from a string:

```
while (n)
  {
    int long v = strtol (s, &e, 10);
    if (v == 0 && strlen (e) > 0)
      {
        ++e;
        if (!e)
          break;
      }
    else
      {
        printf ("%d\n", v);
        --n;
      }
    s = e;
  }
```

This also works for ill-formed input like "5 16 4 blah blah 32".

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you might be better off using a [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) library to do this, seeing as the amount is unknown

Answer (score 0):

You could use strtok and strtol

Comment: You should add the examples of usage and links to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for that. Just curious, why the feedback now? I wrote this two years ago!

Answer (score 0):

What about first using [strtok](http://www.suite101.com/content/string-tokenizing-in-c-programming-a9864) to tokenize the string and then use sscanf?